# Growing a widget vertically when resizing the window (using the grid geometry manager)

Tags: python, tkinter

How can I grow a widget vertically when I make the window larger?

I get a large grey unfilled area at the bottom:

[image]

How can I make the `text` resize vertically? So I get something like this mockup:

[image]

I tried a bunch of of flags to both `root` an `text`, but nothing seems to do this :-/

Example code:

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
root.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

text = tk.Text(root, height=3)
entry = tk.Entry(root)

text.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky=tk.W + tk.E)
entry.grid(row=5, column=0, sticky=tk.W + tk.E)

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Give the row that the widget is in a positive weight, and make sure the text widget has a sticky option for the north and south direction.

```
root.rowconfigure(1, weight=1)
# [...]
text.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky=tk.W + tk.E + tk.N + tk.S)
```

Comment: Thanks; I actually tried this with `rowconfigure(0)`, but apparently you need to use `1` and not `0`...

Comment: @Carpetsmoker:  the text widget is in row 1, so if you want the text widget to grow, you need to configure row 1.

Comment: I would like to add to this answer that by default all widgets have `weight=0`, that means that they won't grow by default.

Comment: @Rinzler: correction: *grid rows and columns* have a default weight of zero, not widgets. Widgets don't have the concept of weight.